# Puppeteer fails to launch chromium in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, puppeteer, chromium

This is my dockerfile code:

```
FROM node:18-alpine As base

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

RUN apk update && apk add curl gnupg \
    && curl --location --silent https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apk add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apk/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apk update \
    && apk add google-chrome-stable --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

USER node
WORKDIR /app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json .

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .
```

My backend is running inside a Docker container and is built with Nest Js. I want to save the PDF file after converting the HTML content. I'm using the Puppeteer library for that, and in order for my conversion to work, I need to run Chromium (whether it is headless or not).

When we run the command "npm i puppeteer," I assumed I didn't need to install Chrome. It worked during development, but for some reason it does not work in a Docker container.

I am not sure that the code in my Docker file will work to install Chrome. I got this code online and pasted it in my Docker file, but it shows the error [image]

any solution to this?

Comment: Will post a solution below, but for discussions-sake, can you use cheerio for this? Im in the middle of a monster scraping problem, and I use cheerio and puppeteer. My whole mentality has been to hold off on using Puppeteer unless I absolutely have to. If youre just loading html and not doing any interaction (assuming no lazy loads) then you might be good to use cheerio which is so so much easier.

Comment: @TomLV I am aware that there are number of libraries that I can use to convert HTML into PDF but I have to use puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using an outdated command, try:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
  wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
  sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Totally just a hunch, but I'm assuming you're using this tutorial: https://dev.to/cloudx/how-to-use-puppeteer-inside-a-docker-container-568c

But it looks like you're using the older solution.

Comment: This is not working.The link at the 3rd line is not working I think. It says ```#0 15.91 ERROR: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main: No such file or directory
#0 15.91 WARNING: Ignoring http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main: No such file or directory```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution I finally got working in Docker.

The current linux user has to be given permissions and puppeteer configured using the configuration file

Also important is to set the `executablePath` to `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` and use `--no-sandbox` mode

using `puppeteer@20.5.0`

make sure to use the relevant official docker image for puppeteer, in this case
`ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:20.5.0`

.puppeteerrc.cjs

```
const { join } = require('path')

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:20.5.0

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app

RUN chown -Rh $user:$user /app
USER $user

COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

index.js

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: 'new',
    slowMo: 25,
    args: [
      '--start-maximized',
      '--no-sandbox',
    ],
    executablePath: '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome',
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

use thios in Dockerfile
`RUN apk add --no-cache \ chromium`

and

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    executablePath: "/usr/bin/chromium",
});
```

in your code